# Transition is not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, transition

Why transition doesn't work in this example in IE?

https://codepen.io/littlesnippets/pen/rxKBWq

I found a lot of answers and I tried to add recommended meta tags, doctype etc. but nothing...

```js
/* Demo purposes only */
$(".hover").mouseleave(
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento);
.snip1361 {
  font-family: 'Quattrocento', Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 315px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #141414;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.snip1361 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.snip1361 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.snip1361 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(77%);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 15px 25px 65px;
}

.snip1361 figcaption:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, transparent 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #ffffff 100%);
}

.snip1361 h3,
.snip1361 p {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.snip1361 h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.snip1361 p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.snip1361 a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.snip1361:hover figcaption,
.snip1361.hover figcaption {
  top: 80px;
}


/* Demo purposes only */

body {
  background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<figure class="snip1361">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample45.jpg" alt="sample45" />
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Bartholemew Shoe</h3>
    <p>Weekends don't count unless you spend them doing something completely pointless.</p>
  </figcaption>
  <a href="#"></a>
</figure>
<figure class="snip1361 hover"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample77.jpg" alt="sample77" />
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Spruce Springclean</h3>
    <p>I'm killing time while I wait for life to shower me with meaning and happiness. -</p>
  </figcaption>
  <a href="#"></a>
</figure>
<figure class="snip1361"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/331810/sample99.jpg" alt="sample99" />
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Desmond Eagle</h3>
    <p>The only skills I have the patience to learn are those that have no real application in life. </p>
  </figcaption>
  <a href="#"></a>
</figure>
```

Comment: Are you asking IE6? Or IE7? Or IE8? Or IE9? Or IE10? Or IE11?

Comment: I found that transition is supported in IE 10+. I have IE 11 and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]? As it is right now, it's not (immediately) clear what should be transitioned.

Comment: Remember to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
.snip1361 figcaption { top: calc(77%); }
```

to

```
.snip1361 figcaption { top: 77%; }
```

> Transitionable properties with `calc()` derived values are not supported below and including IE11 (http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/762719/css3-calc-bug-inside-transition-or-transform)
>
> https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark the correct answer.